# Is Observable as static class member a good practice?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop, rxjs

I started to work on a new Angular project lately, and I see that the common implementation to share state between nonrelated components is using rxjs `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` as static members of the class.

For example:

```js
export class AbcService {
  private static importantData: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  
  static get importantData$(): Observable<any>{
    return AbcService.importantData.asObservable()
  }
}
```

usage:

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
export class DefComponent {
  constructor() {
    AbcService.importantData$.subscribe(...)
  }
}
```

I tried to think of the pros of this approach but, I can't find any significant value by doing that, also it contrasts with the injection concept.

What am I missing, what are the benefits of declaring observables as static class members?

Comment: I have never actually encountered this.. and I can’t think of direct benefits either to be honest..?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. There is no additional advantage of this especially in case of Angular as it ensures that services are singleton and thus no need for this.

However, it could be useful in non-angular scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit here is the benefit of any static method - that is, the method can be called without instantiating the class. The limit is that any static class property the static method uses will be shared among all calls.

However, in this use case, that limit itself is the benefit - that the service should be taken from a single source. This is useful when you use non-injectable services which are not singletons.

---

There is a library I have written for this very purpose. It can create **broadcasters** and broadcast data to multiple receivers. Or it can create **listeners** which can receive data from multiple senders.

It offers many more features such as the ability of creating a receiver before the broadcaster (broadcast from a dynamically loaded component to a static one), namespaces, receiver scoping etc.

It greatly simplifies this use case.

Here is the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-interconnect

Here is a sample for a broadcaster:

````
 let messageStream: IMessageStream = createBroadcaster('home/stateChanged');   //Create a broadcaster```
 
 ...
 ...
 /*Receive from it from another component somewhere in the hierarchy*/
 
 let userReceiver = receiveFrom('home/stateChanged', 'contacts/user', (data, error, complete) => {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(error);
  console.log(complete);
 })
 
 
 '''
 '''
 /*Broadcast messages from the first component*/
 nessageStream.emit('logged-in');
````

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good idea
Because the class must be **testable**.
The class must show its **dependencies** without looking its code.DefComponent depends on AbcService.you must look at the code to know it.
Finally, if you change the name of your static class, you must change it to any file it uses that you are not aware of.
Instead, it is better to use a factory pattern or interface so that it is both testable and shows dependency.
I refer you to read **SOLID Principles.**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Comment: I know SOLID, and my gut feeling is that it's a bad practice. But I'm not familiar enough with OOP and other languages rather than js. Therefore I look for the pros and cons of this approach. Could you please explain why it is not testable? Because you cant inject a testing service? replacing all over the code will happen also with a non-static member. You answer is lack information.

Comment: If your class stores state (data), running multiple tests might effect each other, so writing test will be harder .your sample code is very simple but in large scale maybe it happen.

Comment: Static classes are hard or impossible to mock. So, if you are testing a class depends on the static class, mocking may not be an easy option.